# How to make my own angular bootstrap documentation

Tags: angularjs

Is there way to make, like some template in bootstrap, also angular bootstrap documentation for my application/projects?

Comment: yes use ng-docs you can comment your code and ng-docs creates html files showing stuff like Controller methods functions examples https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation

Comment: Ok, that sound very good, only i don't know hot to access now, i install ngdoc and gdeni but i don't understand completely how to implement ? Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is to install `ng-docs` via npm and grunt via npm when you have that you can comment your code smth like this

```
/**
 * @ngdoc object
 * @name SomeName
 * @description
 * 
 * Some Text
 * 
 * <h2>Screenshot</h2>
 * <img src="SomeImage" style="width:200px; border:1px solid grey" alt="login" />
 */

.controller('someName'......

}])
```

when you have that all you do is run grunt ngdocs on your command line and it should build the docu project which then you can view like a webpage on a local server (xampp for example ) or put it online

Here is the docu link for some more information

[ng-docs docu](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation)

and here is a screenshot of how it looks

[Screenshot](http://image-upload.de/image/YC9eKS/e070fabd23.png)

The Folder needs to look smth like this

```
- someFolder
   - ThisisyourProjectFolder
   - node-modules
   - docs
   - package.json
   - Gruntfile.js
```

And in the commandline you go to somefolder and run grunt ngdocs

Comment: aha ok, now i know that, only that missing is when i install globally dgeni on which file i need to star command line i try dgeni package.json but result is

`module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    ...
`

Comment: you need to install it in your root directory of your project

Comment: someProjectFolder in there you have package.json, the docs folder, the node modules, the gruntfile.js and your projectfolder which contains your index file

Comment: i did that, and get node_modules/ folder inside i get bin,dgeni,grunt,grunt-ngdoc

Comment: i changed my answer so you see the folder Structure

Comment: great, only one more thing, do i copy package.json and Gruntfile.js from grunt-ngdoc ?

Comment: And for last Q, [Screenshot](http://image-upload.de/file/VBgyvb/9b46c164fb.png) i write all on index.html ? Tnx very much i was in hurry y ware very helpful.

Comment: nah ngdocs does that automaticly depending what u enter as @ngdoc on the first line you can do "@ngdoc service" / controller / object / directive filter and as name you can do service.Something

Comment: A say woooww what great thing i will be finish by tomorrow for sure, tnx again